# Cut holes out of a plane three.js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I made a plane that uses simplex noise to elevate some of the vertices.  The elevated vertices represent areas I want to cut out of the plane (think swiss cheese).  I need an actual geometry with holes, so no shaders.

**How can I cut these holes out?**

```
function NoisePlane() {
  const meshRef = useRef();
  const [widthSegments, heightSegments] = [100, 100];

  const vertices = useMemo(() => {
    const geometry = new PlaneGeometry(10, 10, widthSegments, heightSegments);
    const simplex = createNoise2D();
    const threshold = 0.5;
    const positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;

    for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3) {
      const x = positions[i];
      const y = positions[i + 1];
      const z = positions[i + 2];
    
      const noiseValue = simplex(x, y);
      console.log(noiseValue);
    
      positions[i + 2] = noiseValue > threshold ? 0.5 : 0;
    }

    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    return geometry;
  }, [widthSegments, heightSegments]);

  return (
    <mesh ref={meshRef} geometry={vertices}>
      <meshBasicMaterial color={0x00ff00} wireframe />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

[image: wireframe of plane modified by simplex noise.]

Comment: Can you just remove those triangles that have at least one vertex above a certain threshold? Or do you need them to be smoother than that?

Comment: i'd be happy to just remove them to start with, that would be good progress.  ultimately i'd like them smooth, like a camo pattern.

Comment: Removing the triangles should not be hard. You clearly know how to manipulate buffer attribute arrays in Three.js, since you're doing that in your example. To manipulate the triangles, you can edit the index attributes.

Comment: I don't know how to remove the triangles, only move the x,y,z in the buffer...

Comment: Oh, well you can manipulate the indices in much the same way. For instance, you could change the "tall" triangle indices to all 0. Or rearrange the index buffer to skip those triangles completely. I'd be happy to provide an example, but it would be easier with a running demo of your code, on something like JSFiddle or Codesandbox, if you're able to provide.